# Can Visual Studio build using a newer version of msbuild?

Tags: visual-studio

I have both Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2022 on my machine. Visual Studio 2022 seems to have a couple quirks with the way our projects are set up. I know I can build things using the 2022 developer command prompt or in the IDE itself. Is there a way to point 2019 to use the 2022 build tools so that I can use the old IDE with the new tools?